# LinkedList Adding Node compared by size with C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Today, I got a new homework from my teacher.

He told me that this homework might be a sample for final exam.

I tried it for about 2 ~ 3 hours, but I can't get it.

He gave me a simple LinkedList Code. Below in bold is what he wants.

Would you give me some hint about comparing size of Nodes?

**Adding Nodes Compared with pre Node and After Node.**

**2 --> 5 --> 10 --> 20**

**When I InsertMiddleNode( 7 ), Automatically compare input number(7) with ListNode And locate the right Place**

My Goal : **2 --> 5 --> 7(which is my input) --> 10 --> 20**

Teacher's code is below:

```c
    void insertMiddleNode(linkedList_h* L, listNode* pre, int x) {
        listNode* newNode;
        newNode = (listNode*)malloc(sizeof(listNode));
        newNode->data = x;
        if (L == NULL) {                // Empty
            newNode->link = NULL;       // connect
            L->head = newNode;
        }
        else if (pre == NULL) {         // 
            L->head = newNode;          // Insert Node at First
        }
        else {
            newNode->link = pre->link;  // after pre node
            pre->link = newNode;
        }
    }
```

Or could it be possible for implementing the same function in main code?

```c
    int main() {

        linkedList_h* L;
        listNode* p;
        L = createLinkedList_h();

        insertLastNode(L, 1);
        insertLastNode(L, 5);
        insertLastNode(L. 10);
        insertLastNode(L, 20);    // 1 - 5 - 10 - 20

        insertMiddleNode(L, p, 7)  // using p = scanf("%d") with If ( p < pre Node )

        printList(L)  // 2 - 5 - 7 - 10 - 20
    }
```

Comment: It looks like `p` in `main` (or `pre` in `insertMiddleNode`) is supposed to point to the preceding node (i.e. the new node will be inserted after the `pre` node). So you need to make `p` point to the node which has its `data` member set to 5. Does `insertLastNode` return a pointer to the node it created? If so, set `p` to the value returned by `insertLastNode(L, 5);`.

Comment: @Kihyeon Kim Change your teacher. He is a weak programmer. This code snippet     if (L == NULL) {                // Empty
        newNode->link = NULL;       // connect
        L->head = newNode;
} invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: By the way, the teacher's code for `insertMiddleNode` has an error in the handling of `if (L == NULL)` Calling the function with `L` set to `NULL` would result in a null pointer dereference.

Comment: In the second `if/else` branch, you should connect the new node with the node after head first, with `newNode->link = L->head; L->head = newNode`.

Comment: to lan abbott  & vlad from moscow,  thx for comment, but I can't change my teacher. because he is an employee of school. anyway, I understan about L == NULL, It is one of the main problem of code. I try it again now. Thx for comments again.

Comment: @Kihyeon Kim It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: This code would be better written as `*(int *)0 = 3;`

Answer (score 1):

```
void MiddleNode(linkedList_h* L, int x) {
    if (L == null)
         return

    //setp 1: find the previous node
    listNode* prev = null;
    for (listNode* node = L->head; node && node->data < x; node = node->link)
        prev = node;

    //step2: be sure prev is not null
    if (prev == null)
        return;
        //or call inserFirstNode(L, x) and return

    //step 3: call your teacher's function
    insertMiddleNode(L, prev, x);
    return;
}
```

return if L doesn't exist, or you'll crash

the first step is quite simple, loop through the list to find the previous element
but you may end up with null as prev node (either cause the list is empty or x is the smallest), in both case you need to return (or you'll break the list).
Then just call your teacher's function

Comment: Thx for comment, but it doesn't work. I think There will be more problem in my code. Thx